# How to package Unity3d app for Facebook review when use prime[31] plugin?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, prime31

When I use prime[31] plugin, I can't run app in simulator. And I cannot call any [DllImport ("__Internal”)] function in simulator. How should I package my app to Facebook to review?

Error log:
`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_P31", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FacebookManager.o
      objc-class-ref in FacebookBinding.o
      objc-class-ref in SharingBinding.o
      objc-class-ref in TwitterBinding.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_P31Unity)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TwitterManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TwitterBinding.o
  "Alg::Compression::Lzma::decode(Alg::Compression::Lzma::CompressPrefix, void*, unsigned long, unsigned char const*, char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      Pfx::Asm::Lzma::uncompress(unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned char const*, unsigned long) in libiPhone-lib.a(asmlzma.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: Do you solved it somehow?